# How to create dynamic flatlist modal gallery with caption in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to code one dynamic flatlist modal gallery in react native but I do not know where to start, I have added gif file for the output I am looking. It will be very helpful if any body could share the code or give some idea how to go about.

Thanking in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/greedy-apple)

[image]

Here is the working code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let img = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        numColumns={3}
        data={img}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelected(index)}>
            <View style={styles.thumb}>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={selected !== null}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          this.setSelected(null);
        }}>
        <View style={styles.preview}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelected(null)}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text>{'X'}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(00, 00, 255, 0.4)',
              flex: 1,
              marginVertical: 50,
              marginHorizontal: 10,
            }}>
            <Text>{img[selected]}</Text>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                position: 'fixed',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  if (selected > 0) {
                    setSelected(selected - 1);
                  }
                }}>
                <View
                  style={[
                    styles.button,
                    { width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15 },
                  ]}>
                  <Text>{'<'}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  if (selected < img.length - 1) {
                    setSelected(selected + 1);
                  }
                }}>
                <View
                  style={[
                    styles.button,
                    { width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15 },
                  ]}>
                  <Text>{'>'}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    margin: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  preview: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    top: 20,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)',
  },
  button: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Put your image urls in to an array.
- When pressed on the image, set the selected image index and set the modal visible.
- Show the image in the modal from the array using the selected index.
- Left - Right arrows can increase/decrease the selected image index so the image changes.

Comment: it will be great if you could provide some code snippet